# Date conversion for DAO unit tests

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, h2, localdate

I am upgrading our application to a version of the framework that supports Java 8's Date/Time API.  I've updated our entity models to reflect the correct type conversion (date -> LocalDate, timestamp -> LocalDateTime).

I'm now hitting an issue running my unit tests where the converters are attempting to cast java.sql.Date as java.sql.Timestamp.  This is confusing because Timestamp shouldn't be used for these entities.  The testing SQL script uses TO_DATE() to set the dates, like so:

```
INSERT INTO note (id, content, date, owner_id) VALUES (1, 'test content', TO_DATE('17/12/2017', 'DD/MM/YYYY'), 1);
```

And the exception returned is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.sql.Timestamp cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
at com.<redacted>.model.jpa.LocalDateAttributeConverter.convertToEntityAttribute(LocalDateAttributeConverter.java:8)
at org.hibernate.metamodel.model.convert.internal.JpaAttributeConverterImpl.toDomainValue(JpaAttributeConverterImpl.java:45)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.converter.AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter$2.doConversion(AttributeConverterSqlTypeDescriptorAdapter.java:140)
... 64 more
```

from a simple AttributeConverter<>:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDate, Date> {

@Override
public Date convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDate locDate) {
    return (locDate == null ? null : Date.valueOf(locDate));
}

@Override
public LocalDate convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) {
    return (sqlDate == null ? null : sqlDate.toLocalDate());
}
}
```

I can understand it having an issue casting from Timestamp to Date but Timestamp shouldn't be involved at all here.

Entity for completeness:

```
@XmlRootElement
@Entity(name = "notes")
public class Note implements ModelObject {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "owner_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private User user;
private String content;
private LocalDate date;
// getters/setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Not sure if this affects it, but I have also created AttributeConverters for LocalTime and LocalDateTime.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalTime, Time> {

@Override
public Time convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalTime localTime) {
    return (localTime == null ? null : Time.valueOf(localTime));
}

@Override
public LocalTime convertToEntityAttribute(Time sqlTime) {
    return (sqlTime == null ? null : sqlTime.toLocalTime());
}
}



@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class LocalDateTimeAttributeConverter implements AttributeConverter<LocalDateTime, Timestamp> {

@Override
public Timestamp convertToDatabaseColumn(LocalDateTime locDateTime) {
    return (locDateTime == null ? null : Timestamp.valueOf(locDateTime));
}

@Override
public LocalDateTime convertToEntityAttribute(Timestamp sqlTimestamp) {
    return (sqlTimestamp == null ? null : sqlTimestamp.toLocalDateTime());
}
}
```

Using Hibernate 5.3.0.Final and H2 1.4.197 with hibernate-java8 library.

Comment: Please specify what version of hibernate and jpa you’re using.

Comment: Found that the AttributeConverters weren't being applied based on Type.  Hint was in the stacktrace.  It attempts to cast the Timestamp to Date when calling attribute.convertToEntityAttribute(Date sqlDate) instead of calling the correct converter.  Have removed the converters in favor of using Hibernate's proprietary solution.